# Cannot Access Encrypted Files in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-explorer, encryption, decryption

I use an external USB drive to backup files ( FREECOM MOBILE DRIVE XXS NTFS 270GB External Drive (USB) ). I have been doing quite a few years and continue to do so on a weekly basis.

During this time, I bought a new laptop (Windows 10) and created a new user with a new computer name (see below):

**Old Username/Laptop**

Billy@BILLJYELITEBOOK (account/laptop does not exist anymore)

**New Username/Laptop**

Billy@BILLYJ-ENVY

Note1: Both user accounts had/have Administrator privileges.

Note2: The Windows version on the current laptop is as follows:

**Edition: Windows 10 Home**

**Version: 21H2**

**Installed on: 30/‎03/‎2021**

**OS build: 19044.2006**

**Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0**

I continued using the external USB drive with the new laptop to back up files.

I then noticed while trying to access older files that were backed up from the old laptop/user account, that I was unable to do so.

The older files/folders on the external drive are now displayed in "green" and when I try to access/edit a file, I receive the following error message:

**ERROR
Can not open file "F:\THIRD-DIVIDEND-BACKUP-DIR\31032019\THIRD-DIVIDEND\PRODUCTION\SKY-RACING\SKY-TOMORROW\SINGAPORE-TOMORROW\ARCHIVE\20190328\singapore1.racedetails"**

After a bit of research, I discovered that the files have somehow become "encrypted" and the files/folders are owned by the old user (Billy@BILLJYELITEBOOK) from my old laptop (which is me).

Note3: No encryption was performed by me on any of these files/folders.

I then proceeded to update the Properties on the external drive and set up a new Group called "Everyone" and granted all permissions (Full Control, Modify, Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, Read, Write) to the "Everyone" group. This did not change anything. I still cannot access/edit the encrypted files.

Note4: Advanced Security Settings on the external drive under Properties shows that all Principals have Access set to Full Control. This includes:

****Authenticated Users, SYSTEM, Administrators (BILLYJ-ENVY/Administrators), Everyone, Users (BILLYJ-ENVY/Users)****

I then went to a specific folder and ran CIPHER:

***cipher /D***

**Decrypting files in F:\THIRD-DIVIDEND-BACKUP-DIR\31032019\THIRD-DIVIDEND\PRODUCTION\SKY-RACING\SKY-TOMORROW\SINGAPORE-TOMORROW\ARCHIVE\20190328

singapore1.racedetails [ERR]
singapore1.racedetails: The file system does not support encryption.**

Note5: I am only using 1 file in my example here. There are actually 57 Folders with thousands of files contained within.

I then ran **CIPHER /C** to display information on the encrypted file:

**E singapore1.racedetails**

**Compatability Level: Windows XP/Server 2003**

Users who can decrypt:

**Billy(Billy@BILLYJELITEBOOK)**

**Certificate thumbprint: 7AA0 58E7 6C7C 2D58 204D 8C0E 70E2 B6A5 E6A5 E1A3**

**No recovery certificate found.**

**Key information cannot be retrieved.**

**The specified file could not be decrypted.**

It appears that all the files/folders that were backed up prior to me purchasing the new laptop are owned by my old account from my old laptop.

As a test, I then created a text file in the aforementioned folder and it was created without encryption (see results from CIPHER command below):

**Listing F:\THIRD-DIVIDEND-BACKUP-DIR\31032019\THIRD-DIVIDEND\PRODUCTION\SKY-RACING\SKY-TOMORROW\SINGAPORE-TOMORROW\ARCHIVE\20190328**

**New files added to this directory will be encrypted.**

**U NEW-FILE-TEST.txt**

**E singapore1.racedetails**

Note6: U = unencrypted, E = encrypted

After a bit more digging, it appears that the owner of the files/folders is my old account from my old laptop which has a different Certificate Thumbprint:

**User: Billy(Billy@BILLJYELITEBOOK)**

**Certificate thumbprint: 7AA0 58E7 6C7C 2D58 204D 8C0E 70E2 B6A5 E6A5 E1A3**

I believe that this is what is preventing me from accessing the older files/folders.

Does anyone know how I can reset all the files/folders so I can access/open them?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like the site bumped this question - If you don't have access to your old laptop, (and the certificate for your user on it), then you will unfortunately **not** be able to access these encrypted files

Comment: Thanks @Cpt.Whale Yeah, I’ve had to give up on this as I’ve tried/researched everything I could. There are some mobs out there that claim to be able to recover encrypted files (for a healthy fee) but I’m kinda sceptical. Oh well. Thanks again!